# Magento SOAP API v2, cant get order information

Tags: api, magento, soap

Im trying to get the order information from the V2 API. But none of the sales* releated methods seem to work.

I can:
 - view the wsdl
 - connect/login successfully (user has all resource access)
 - Call many methods (non-sales order related), and see results

Connection code:

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://mywebsitedomain/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
 $session = $client->login('myuser', 'mypassword');
```

working calls:

```
 $result = $client->customerCustomerList($session);
 $result = $client->directoryCountryList($session);
 $result = $client->catalogProductAttributeList($session); //returns empty array
 $result = $client->magentoInfo($session);
 $result = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session);
```

Non working calls:

```
 $result = $client->salesOrderInfo($session, '100022209'); //valid order number
 $result = $client->salesOrderList($session);
```

Error recieved for non working calls:

```
 Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path
```

Also tried different call formats:

```
 $params = array('filter' => array(
     array('key' => 'status', 'value' => 'pending'),
     array('key' => 'customer_is_guest', 'value' => '1')
 ));
 $result = $client->salesOrderList($session, $params);
```

Does anyone know why the sales-related methods do not seem to be working here?

Answer (score 1):

A third party module was to blame. Overriding a config it shouldnt!

```
    <v2>
        <resources_function_prefix>
            <order>pinordersOrder</order>
            <pin>pinordersPin</pin>
        </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>
```

Removing this solved the issue.
V1 soap api still worked, but we wanted to integrate into a third party service that required the use of V2.